# Shared workspaces available in SLX.cloud free version?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I wrote a small C++ application that I want to test for performance in different multicore platforms. I'll get help from a coworker to do this, but I'll need to share my workspace with him (he's overseas). Is this available on the cloud SLX, and if so, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thanks for trying it out! I am the product manager of [SLX.cloud](https://slx.cloud) (a free online version of our multicore optimization tools), so if you have any further questions you can ask me directly.

Currently, [SLX.cloud](https://slx.cloud) offers a feature called factories to share your workspace. Factories are templates used to generate new or open existing workspaces with a URL.

You can replicate a workspace by creating such a factory. There are two ways to create a workspace:

#### 1. Within the running IDE

The easiest way to create a factory is by going to `Workspace -> Create Factory` from within the main menu of the IDE in a running workspace.

[image: Workspace Create Factory]

You can set a name for the factory and click on `Create` to generate the factory. The Factory URL will be displayed in the field underneath. Next to it you can either start or further configure it.

[image: Factory Dialog]

#### 2. Via the Dashboard

You can also create a factory through the Dashboard by clicking on `Factories -> Create Factory`. Next you will see a list of your workspaces. You can select one and click the `Create` button on the bottom of the page to start the factory creation.

[image: Dashboard Factory]

After clicking `Create`, the factory is already created and the URLs are displayed on the top of the page.

[image: Dashboard Factory Link]

#### NOTE:

A factory does **not** replicate your file system within the workspace. It replicates the stack (usually `silexica/tools:latest`), all set up projects and all run configurations.

Therefore,
- if you have installed software via `apt-get` or other means, it will not be included in the factory. To include those as well, you need to create a custom stack.
- if you have changed files after importing a project via git, make sure these files are committed to your repository. Otherwise they will not be included in the factory.

### Creating a Custom Stack

To install additional software within a workspace or a factory, you need to create a custom stack. The details are described in [Runtime Recipes](https://docs.slx.cloud/docs/devops/runtime-recipes/index.html).